# exclude partitionkey and rowkey in web api response of azure table storage

Tags: azure, asp.net-web-api2, azure-storage, azure-table-storage

I serached in web, but didn't find any solution.please help me in resolving this.

**Question:** i have a webapi with azure table storage, when i query azure table the webapi json response included with partitionkey and rowkey.
i want my web api response excluded with partitionkey and rowkey of azure table.

**Current output:**{*"partitionkey":"test","Rowkey":"abc"*,"name":"user","email":"test@test.com","domain":"qwe"}

**Expected output:**
{"name":"user","email":"test@test.com","domain":"qwe"}

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Your question is not clear. Are you asking us to provide with the completed to do the job? If so, that's not what we do here. Have you already written some code and it's not working? If so, provide the code and the error message.

Answer (score 1):

> when i query azure table, the webapi json response included with partitionkey and rowkey. i want my web api response excluded with partitionkey and rowkey of azure table.

You could try to use **query projection** to return a limited set of properties from the entities while selecting entities from Azure Table storage. The following query is for your reference.

```
TableQuery<EmployeeEntity> EmpQuery = table.CreateQuery<EmployeeEntity>();
var query = (from ep in EmpQuery
             where ep.PartitionKey == "pkvalue" && ep.RowKey== "rkvalue"
             select new { Fname = ep.FirstName, Lname = ep.LastName}).AsTableQuery();
var emps = query.Execute();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use property [SelectColumns](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/microsoft.windowsazure.storage.table.tablequery.selectcolumns.aspx) in [TableQuery](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/azure/microsoft.windowsazure.storage.table.tablequery.aspx) class to specify the columns you want to query from Azure Storage Table Service.

Comment: i have 20 columns in table(i have 10 tables in diff queries), instead of adding all columns as selected can we have only to remove partitionkey and rowkey, timestamp...

Comment: i have 20 columns in each table(totally 10 tables in diff queries), instead of adding all columns as selectedcolumns, can we have something only to remove partitionkey , rowkey and timestamp.

Comment: Sorry, I don't know how to exclude columns.

Comment: With Azure Tables, you can only specify the columns (attributes) you want service to return. To remove something, you would need to handle in your code. HTH.

Comment: As Gaurav stated - you cannot exclude columns. PartitionKey, RowKey, Timestamp & ETag are [sadly] always returned regardless if you need/want them!

Answer (score 1):

The key point to exclude PartitionKey and RowKey from result is to set **ProjectSystemProperties** of TableRequestOptions to **false**.

So the code above should be modified like this:

```
var emps = query.Execute(new TableRequestOptions { ProjectSystemProperties = false });
```

Another working example:

```
var query = new TableQuery<Event>()
    .Where(
        TableQuery.GenerateFilterCondition(
            "PartitionKey", QueryComparisons.Equal, partitionKey))
    .Select(new[] { "Id" });

var results = table.ExecuteQuery(query, 
    new TableRequestOptions { ProjectSystemProperties = false });
```

Then you will get response like this:

```
{"odata.etag":"W/\"datetime'2017-10-27T08%3A05%3A40.6551979Z'\"","Id":"Event-1" },
{"odata.etag":"W/\"datetime'2017-10-27T09%3A05%3A40.6551979Z'\"","Id":"Event-2" },
...
```

To avoid odata.etag in result, specify PayloadFormat in TableRequestOptions and get exactly what you want:

```
var results = table.ExecuteQuery(query, 
    new TableRequestOptions { 
        ProjectSystemProperties = false, 
        PayloadFormat = TablePayloadFormat.JsonNoMetadata 
});
```

Result:

```
{ "Id":"Event-1" },{ "Id":"Event-2" },...
```